# CCM PFC - Duty Cycle and Pout Misunderstanding

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-factor-correction

Suppose a PFC working in CCM. Vout is hold constant thanks to the duty cycle.  Pout is also constant over the time. Suppose the input rms voltage Vin_RMS drops ! For a CCM boost PFC, the duty cycle is given according to the following relation (at least the average duty cycle as the duty cycle is varying for adjusting the input current to a sinusoidal waveform) : $$D = \frac{Vout - Vin}{Vout} $$
So if Vin drops, the duty cycle increases.
Then Isense (the current sensed by the PFC controller which is equal to the input current) according to the datasheet, (I verified the property just for curiosity not because I thought it was wrong) :

[image]

$$Iisns = \frac{(1-D)*Vm}{Gdc*Risns}$$

Vm correspond to the output voltage of the error amplifier (between Vref and the feedback output voltage). The maximum Vm is given into the datasheet, we will consider it at its maximum (worst case), so we can simplify the expression as follows :

$$Iisns = k*(1-D)$$

So if Vin decreases, the average duty cycle increases, and it means that the maximum admissible Iisns (input current) has decreased too. What does it means ? The input power is lower as Vin and Iin have decreased. Nevertheless Pout is still the same. Where is my mistake ? The input power shoould be the same. So the rms input current should increase ! ?

If you are interested here are the sources : 
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/an-1166.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153559aabdf1128
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/ir1155spbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c431f9164b
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/an-1077.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153559563801007

Comment: Are you aware that during a single cycle of AC, the duty cycle starts off as minimum and becomes a maximum at the peak of the rectified cycle. I’m asking this because it may be something that hasn’t sunk in. PFC boost converters do things differently so that the cyclic shape to current taken from the AC supply looks like a resistive load.

Comment: Hi, actually I know that the duty cycle cannot be constant as the input current could not be sinusoidal, nevertheless I though that the duty cycle shoud be maximum at the beginning of the AC rectified cycle and minimum at the peak.

Comment: Actually my question is pretty bad, but we could think that the Rsns (indirectly maximum Isense) have to be selected at input maximum voltage for maximum output power. Then if the input voltage decreases, it will be possible to draw more power from the input before clamping the duty cycle due to maximum Vm, something like this. I will try to think about it !

Comment: I think you need to consider, pwm cycle by cycle, what the duty is. You could ignore the input being a sinewave and consider that the AC waveform is in fact a triangle wave. I say this because you can more readily see that the energy per pwm cycle taken has to be proportionately lower at lower instantaneous voltages AND it’s easier to see how pwm duty changes as input voltage rises and falls cyclically. I’ve never done this calculation so it’s new for me but I’d be thinking about a triangle shaped AC waveform. I could be wrong of course, just gut feeling. It would help if you defined Iisns.

Comment: You re right ! I need to do it !